# How to get the Popup URL in NewWindow2 Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a web browser in my windows forms app. When a popup is about to open, I use this code to open the popup url in the parent web browser.

```
    private SHDocVw.WebBrowser nativeBrowser;
    //wb is the web browser control in the designer

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        nativeBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)wb.ActiveXInstance;
        nativeBrowser.NewWindow2 += nativeBrowser_NewWindow2;
        nativeBrowser.NewWindow3 += nativeBrowser_NewWindow3;
    }

    private void nativeBrowser_NewWindow2(ref object ppDisp, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        ppDisp = wb.ActiveXInstance;
    }

    private void nativeBrowser_NewWindow3(ref object ppDisp, ref bool Cancel, uint dwFlags, string bstrUrlContext, string bstrUrl)
    {
        Cancel = true;
        wb.Navigate(bstrUrl);
    }
```

I'm using Microsoft Internet Controls COM reference (1.1). In some cases the NewWindow3 event is fired and in others cases the NewWindow2 event. The code in the NewWindow3 event works well, however the code in the NewWindow2 event doesn't work. I don´t know how to get the url in this event. How could I get it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How will you open your pop up? By clicking a link?. Is it possible to give the website address

Comment: The popup url is generated automatically by the webpage when clicking a button, it isn't the same in every case.

Comment: I got the answer on social.msdn.microsoft.com, The answer is to use the BeforeNavigate2 event to get the url.

Comment: Can someone please explain what is newwindow2 and newwindow3 and when should I use what ?